# mailcatcher install in GIT Action suddenly fails

Tags: ruby, github-actions, mailcatcher

Since yesterday the same install process using mailcatcher in an github actions fails.
Operating system tested with Ubuntu latest and 20.04

The way mailcatcher gets installed:

```
- name: Install & run mailcatcher
  run: |
    sudo gem install mailcatcher --no-update-sources --no-document
    mailcatcher
```

Nothing changed so far. Any idea?

```
Run sudo gem install mailcatcher --no-update-sources --no-document
  sudo gem install mailcatcher --no-update-sources --no-document
  mailcatcher
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed eventmachine-1.0.9.1
...
Successfully installed daemons-1.4.1
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed thin-1.5.1
Successfully installed skinny-0.2.4
Successfully installed mailcatcher-0.8.2
13 gems installed
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:168:in `require': cannot load such file -- mail/indifferent_hash (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:168:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:156:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mail-2.8.0/lib/mail.rb:14:in `<module:Mail>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mail-2.8.0/lib/mail.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.8.2/lib/mail_catcher/mail.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.8.2/lib/mail_catcher/smtp.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.8.2/lib/mail_catcher.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.8.2/lib/mail_catcher.rb:233:in `rescue_port'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.8.2/lib/mail_catcher.rb:182:in `block in run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run_machine'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.8.2/lib/mail_catcher.rb:180:in `run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.8.2/bin/mailcatcher:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/mailcatcher:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/mailcatcher:23:in `<main>'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- mail/indifferent_hash (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mail-2.8.0/lib/mail.rb:14:in `<module:Mail>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mail-2.8.0/lib/mail.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.8.2/lib/mail_catcher/mail.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.8.2/lib/mail_catcher/smtp.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.8.2/lib/mail_catcher.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.8.2/lib/mail_catcher.rb:233:in `rescue_port'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.8.2/lib/mail_catcher.rb:182:in `block in run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run_machine'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.8.2/lib/mail_catcher.rb:180:in `run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/mailcatcher-0.8.2/bin/mailcatcher:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/mailcatcher:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/mailcatcher:23:in `<main>'
Starting MailCatcher v0.8.2
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

- Tried different ubuntu installs and lower ruby versions

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in the mail gem right now -- see [this issue](https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/1489) on their github.

You'll need to force a downgrade to version `2.7.1` of their gem in your gemfile:

```
gem "mail", "~> 2.7.1"
```

Comment: I managed it by doing this:
https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/528#issuecomment-1339116112